# getting first rows from duplicates depending on one column MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB version 10.2.21

There are multiple rows with duplicate user_id(one of the column).

I want to get first occurrence of each user_id but not just user_id but all rows that is associated with first occurrence of user_id.

```
select 
  distinct user_id,
from 
  user_table
where 
  user_id in (a,b,c,d,e,f,....) and 
  date = '2020-02-25';
```

this correctly gives me all distinct, now when I try to add associated columns

```
EXPLAIN
select 
  distinct user_id,
  ST_X(location) as lng
from 
  user_table
where 
  user_id in (a,b,c,d,e,f,....) and 
  date = '2020-02-25';
```

it tells me that I will get 2+ million rows... I only have 3000 unique user_id
I want to get only first occurring user_id with its associated location.

Since my database is very large I need to take full advantage of indexes otherwise it will break.

my index is [user_id, date] where user_id is 1st index and date is 2nd index.

So My question is how to get unique(first occurring = most upper row) user information by using indexes therefore my db does not break?

so if there is

```
  user_id   location
    1       (123.22, 22.33)
    1       (111.22, 22.12)
    2       (155.33, 41.23)
    2       (160.41, 12.31)
```

I would get

```
user_id   location
   1       (123.22, 22.33)
   2       (155.33, 41.23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation if you only one one location:

```
select user_id, ST_X(min(location)) as lng
from user_table
where user_id in (a,b,c,d,e,f,....) and 
      date = '2020-02-25'
group by user_id;
```

Comment: thanks, what is min(location) for?? When I run it it will still return same amount of rows, 2649544

Comment: @Ambleu . . . This should return one row per user.  As per your question, that is not 2+ million rows.

Comment: You mean even though I run it in EXPLAIN statement and says rows = 2+ mil, when I actually run the code it will return row per user?

Comment: @Ambleu . . . It needs to process all the rows, but it is returning only one row per user.  The `ST_X()` function is run *after* the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: is min(location) giving me lowest longitude values that each user has?

Comment: @Ambleu . . . Yes.  You don't seem to specify which one you want when there are multiple values.

Comment: how to get location from first occurence of user

Comment: @Ambleu . . . Your question provides no information on how to determine the "first" occurrence.

Comment: first occurence = > if there are 10 rows with same user_id, first row.

Comment: @Ambleu . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" row unless a column specifies the ordering.